# how to make day in mysql or java

Tags: java, mysql

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, '2012-06-04 13:13:55', '2012-06-05 15:20:18')
```

i want totals

day 2 
 but mysql show 1 day

Comment: because it's more than 1 full day but lesser than 2 full days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the difference between them is *1 days 2 hours 6 minutes 23 seconds* which is obviously not *2 days* so if you want 2 days to be the result just add 1 to the result obtained.

```
 SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2012-06-04 13:13:55', '2012-06-05 15:20:18')+1;
```